# Setting DateTimePicker to show specific time range e.g. working hours only

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to configure my kendoDateTimePicker to show 9am to 6pm only. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's has been a while since this question has been asked. but i will add my response for future reference.

kendo DateTimePicker does not support adding a range to the TimePicker. But you can add your own widget that does that.

```
(function($) {
        var dateTimePicker = kendo.ui.DateTimePicker;

        var MyWidget = dateTimePicker.extend({

            init: function(element, options) {
                dateTimePicker.fn.init.call(this, element, options);
            },
            startTime: function(startTime) {
                var timeViewOptions = this.timeView.options;
                timeViewOptions.min = startTime;
                this.timeView.setOptions(timeViewOptions);
            },
            endTime: function(endTime) {
                var timeViewOptions = this.timeView.options;
                timeViewOptions.max = endTime;
                this.timeView.setOptions(timeViewOptions);
            },
            options: {
                name: "CustomDateTimePicker"
            }
        });

        kendo.ui.plugin(MyWidget);

    })(jQuery);
```

Then you can call your `CustomDateTimePicker` like this :

```
var datePicker = $("#date-picker").kendoCustomDateTimePicker().data("kendoCustomDateTimePicker");
    datePicker.startTime("07:00");
    datePicker.endTime("11:00");
```

[jsfiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/waelkat/x0ttxnn2/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
     var startDateReference = $('.startDate').kendoDateTimePicker({
        format: "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss",
        value : new Date(),
     }).data("kendoDateTimePicker");

     startDateReference.timeView.options.min = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 7, 30, 0);
     startDateReference.timeView.options.max = new Date(2000, 0, 1, 18, 00, 0);
```

This is working for me

Comment: `startDateReference.timeView.setOptions({  
     min: new Date(2000, 0, 1, 7, 30, 0),  
     max: new Date(2000, 0, 1, 18, 00, 0)  
});`  
  
works better for me

Comment: sgissinger's solution worked for me too whereas Danny's did not.  Edit?

Answer (score 2):

With Kendo [`DateTimePicker`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker) you can select the `min` and `max` dates but not a time range for each day **BUT** you can do it with [`TimePicker`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/timepicker).

Maybe you can decompose your UI in [`DatePicker`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker) and `TimePicker` and then choose [`max`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/timepicker#max-datedefault) and [`min`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/timepicker#min-datedefault) for conforming your time range.

Answer (score 1):

I just put together this hack, because I felt that Datetime pickers should be used for picking a date and a time instead of having the weird ui of having a datepicker and a timepicker that are used to compose a single value:

```
    $('#NewScheduledDateTime_timeview > li').each(function () {   

        bool removeTimeCondition = /* code to determine if time should be removed */

        if (removeTimeCondition)
            $(this).remove();
    })
```

The id of the list will be different. To find it, expand the time list and 'inspect element' of one of the times with your favorite browser's dev tools.

I ought to mention that this is liable to break if the Kendo UI is updated to a newer version. Like I said, it is a hack. But then again, even non-hacky things break when we tried updating the version of Kendo UI. Lessons learned: don't use Kendo UI.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is doing. You get 'txt' but do nothing with it. Is timeview an attribute of DateTimePickers?

Comment: Back when I was working with Kendo UI, the DateTime pickers listed each time value (hours and minutes) as <li> elements somewhere within the DateTimePicker element. So, I used jquery to select all the <li> elements in the DateTimePicker. Then you can use either the filter() function, or simply iterate over those <li> elements and remove ones that you wish to disable. I edited out the txt thing - it was there simply to show how to get at the time value.

Comment: NewScheduledDateTime_timeview just happened to be the id that Kendo asigned to the DateTimePicker.

Comment: Brilliant solution!