# How can I set min max selectable time for Kendo Datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried to use Kendo Datetimepicker's configuration to set min time starts at 09:00 AM.

like below:

```
    $("#txtAppt_Date").kendoDateTimePicker({
                    format: 'ddd M/d/yyyy h:mm tt',
                    min: new Date(2017, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0)
     });
```

But I am only allow to set 2017-01-01's time only. Not work for 2017-01-02 or any other dates.

I want to have range between 09:00 AM to 11:00 PM for this Kendo Datetimepicker.

Please help.

Thanks.

**Update**
This question is solved: I referenced [Setting DateTimePicker to show specific time range e.g. working hours only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500397/setting-datetimepicker-to-show-specific-time-range-e-g-working-hours-only/39273243#39273243)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [min](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#configuration-min) and [max](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#configuration-max) as follows:

```
<input id="datetimepicker" />
<script>
$("#datetimepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
    value: new Date(2011, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0),
    min: new Date(2011, 0, 1, 9, 0, 0),
    max: new Date(2011, 0, 1, 23, 0, 0)
});
</script>
```

Pay attention that you should provide a `value` within the range of `min` and `max`.

See the embedded links above for more information.

Thanks to @Erik, here's a [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shfm16af/).

**UPDATE**
If what you want is to restrict the time 9-23 across *multiple* days, then there's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39273243/5117733) that demos it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/45j8zee6/)

Comment: Please read my queston. It won't work for 2011-01-02 to have min 08:00AM!!

Comment: Try it on your own, you won't have min time (ex. 08:00AM) for any other dates than 2011-1-1. Try pick 2011-1-2 and see you can select 07:00AM or not.

Comment: @SeongKim you should provide a `value` within the range of `min` and `max`. Answer has been updated

Comment: Why not [make a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shfm16af/) and fiddle with it? :)  @SeongKim is right. When picking a time for 2011-1-2 change the min and max again and value should always be in range on min and max.

Comment: @ErikKralj good idea, I'll do it next time, now I'll just steal yours ;)

Comment: @Tali Fair enough! :)